# how to add append dynamic value at end of awscli output for each line

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to get vpc details for all region excluding default vpc in a particular account.Problem is awscli does not have attribute for describe-vpcs to query the region.
So i am trying to include region which i got using describe-region along with vpc ouput,but it includes region for default vpc as well.

actual output:

```
10.0.0.0/16     My-lab-vpc      vpc-abcd  ap-south-1 eu-west-3 eu-west-2 eu-west-1

10.0.0.0/16     myvpc     vpc-asdasd52281  us-east-1 us-east-2 us-west-1
```

expected output: ( it should write only the region along with vpc details where there is no default vpc)

```
10.0.0.0/16     My-lab-vpc      vpc-abcd  ap-south-1 

10.0.0.0/16     myvpc     vpc-asdasd52281  us-east-1
```

Here is the code:

```
for region in `aws ec2 describe-regions --output text| cut -f4`
do
   aws ec2 describe-vpcs --region $region --output text --query 'Vpcs[*]. 
   {VpcId:VpcId,CidrBlock:CidrBlock}' --filters "Name=isDefault,Values=false" >> $output_file
   sed -i "s/$/ $region/" $output_file
done
```

Comment: Please post the output coming from: `aws ec2 describe-regions --output text`

Comment: Output for aws ec2 describe-regions --output text| cut -f4

eu-north-1
ap-south-1
eu-west-3
eu-west-2
eu-west-1
ap-northeast-2
ap-northeast-1
sa-east-1
ca-central-1
ap-southeast-1
ap-southeast-2
eu-central-1
us-east-1
us-east-2
us-west-1
us-west-2

Comment: My cli command extract all vpc details for all region .Problem is how to include region as well in the output for them. AWS CLI does not have region parameter in describe-vpc command.

Comment: Side-note: For the first line, you can use `aws ec2 describe-regions --query Regions[].[RegionName] --output text`